# Automatic calling of base class functions

Tags: c++, class, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around some more advanced points of C++ classes as well as possible (or at least with GNU) compiler/built in functions. All of which based on a logger concept for a (large and extensive) work project . Which brings me to this psuedo-code:

```
class Base {
     public:
           void increment(){
               ++m_Val;
           }
     private:
           static int m_Val;
};
class Above : private Base{
     public:
           void doA(){
                //Foo
           }
           void doB(){
               //Bar
           }
};
```

That having been shown as a concept; is there a way so that the mere inheritance of base allows `doA()` and `doB()` to implicitly call the base function `increment()` without me actually adding the function call to `increment()` in every single function of every single class that inherits it? If not a direct answer, is there a particular term for what I want to do is called? Or is it offered as a part of Boost or other libraries?

Comment: i dont think that exists.

Comment: You might be interested in [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: @DanielA.White  Definitely what I was afraid of. I know C++ is still a 'growing' language, but wasn't sure if there was a way to do that yet or prior with some 'hacky code'

Comment: We need a description of what you're trying to accomplish to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper As I said at the bottom, although I'll add a little more to it: I want multiple (Dozens) of classes to inherit `Base`, and thus in doing so all of their functions that they have automatically call (in this case) `Increment()` automatically. Other than having to copy and paste `Increment()` 9000 times and cluttering the code up.

Progressively, it would become a part of a stack trace or logger.

Comment: @M4rc I did assume it was to be a logging class but you worded your question in such a way to rule that out. But then again, the example code doesn't really exemplify at all how it's related to logging. Otherwise there's many of questions on SO about logging techniques.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Certainly understandable -- and  I tried to make it generic because most people point others in the direction of the multiple things that are out in the git world; which due to Intellectual Property and what not that is being worked on, my superiors are drastically against open source stuff. Not smart of them -- but all the same I don't make the rules.

Comment: With the proposed overloading of `operator.` you could make a smart reference that holds the counter. But that may not land until C++20.

Comment: Thats's certainly a step in the right direction! I was thinking of how an object could be created on function call (but not be in-scope, etc) but that harbors the same issues as all other suggestions: Copy and pasting all the calls into the base.  Perhaps C++ just isn't where I need it to be at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stumbling on to this by pure accident; the solution that most closely resembles what I'm looking for is called "Execute-Around pointer" as defined [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer). Particularly the section relating to:

> Often times it is necessary to execute a functionality before and after every member function call of a class.

Which is represented on  the following code snippet taken from aformentioned link.

```
class VisualizableVector {
  public:
    class proxy {
      public:
        proxy (vector<int> *v) : vect (v) {
          std::cout << "Before size is: " << vect->size ();
        }
        vector<int> * operator -> () {
          return vect;
        }
        ~proxy () {
          std::cout << "After size is: " << vect->size ();
        }
      private:
        vector <int> * vect;
    };
    VisualizableVector (vector<int> *v) : vect(v) {}    
    proxy operator -> () {
       return proxy (vect);
    }
  private:
    vector <int> * vect;
};
int main()
{
  VisualizableVector vecc (new vector<int>);
  //...
  vecc->push_back (10); // Note use of -> operator instead of . operator
  vecc->push_back (20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve similar effect is provide a method for overriding and expose a different public method that calling preconditions and postconditions.

```
class Base {
     public:
           void increment(){
               ++m_Val;
               std::cout << m_Val << '\n';
           }
           void doA(){
                increment();
                implA();
           }
           void doB(){
               increment();
               implB();
           }
    protected:
        virtual void implA() = 0;
        virtual void implB() = 0;

     private:
           int m_Val;
};
class Above : private Base{
    public:
    using Base::doA;
    using Base::doB;
     protected:
        virtual void implA() override {
            std::cout << "a\n";
        }
        virtual void implB() override {
            std::cout << "b\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    Above a;
    a.doA();
    a.doB();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7d2b0c068191cae)

Comment: Only issue I see is that would require me to replicate (or minimally copy and paste) all of the functions from any class that would inherit `Base`, which is kinda the opposite (but yet still expected) hope I had.

Comment: Unfortunately C++ is not dynamic enough to achieve your desired effect without copy & paste. Another solution is use macro to reduce the amount of duplicated code. Otherwise you can use code generator to generate duplicated code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, sadly -- A macro for the whole interface. Maybe someone might have a work around.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly define when you want your base method to be called, but it can be done by abstracting away the call to increment - try something like this pattern (pseudo-code, using Java terminology as I'm not as immediately familiar with the equivalent C++ syntax but you should get the gist of it):

```
abstract class Base {
     public:
           void increment(){
               ++m_Val;
           }
           void doA(){
                increment();
                doAInternal();
           }
           void doB(){
               increment();
               doBInternal();
           }
     protected: 
           abstract void doBInternal();
           abstract void doAInternal();
     private:
           static int m_Val;
};
class Above : private Base{
     public:
           void doAInternal(){
                //Foo
           }
           void doBInternal(){
               //Bar
           }
};
```